# Power Automate to Extract SharePoint Excel Structured Table from Specific Excel File Version History

Tags: excel, sharepoint, power-automate

I have an Excel file located in a document library, periodically multiple users will update the structured table in the Excel file at any point of time. Is there a way for me to retrieve Structured Table from past version Excel file?

I know it is feasible using List Rows Present in a Table for latest version. But, I need to retrieve previous version's Structured table. Note: not to retrieve the file versions, but the content inside the excel file of previous version

I had tried with Get Content but not able to Parse JSON. For List Rows in a Table approach, I am specifying the File field to "_vti_history/512/Document Library/File.xlsm" but the error pop up not able to find Table; I am sure the Table is available in version id 512 Excel file.